# Constantes definidas en PHP error Use of undefined constant

Tags: php, undefined, constantes

Tengo un fichero en la carpeta principal del proyecto llamado core.php donde tengo definidas algunas constantes con direcciones directas a carpetas del proyecto:

```
define( "APP_DIR", "app/");
define( "CSS_DIR", "app/css/");
define( "JS_DIR", "app/js/");
define( "IMG_DIR", "app/img/");
define( "LIBS_DIR", "app/libs/");
define( "VIEWS_DIR", "views/");
define( "HTML_DIR" , "views/html/");
define( "ERROR_DIR", "views/error/");
define( "LAYOUT_DIR", "views/layout/");
define( "CONTROL_DIR", "controller/");
define( "MODEL_DIR", "model/");
```

Y desde el index hago un require de este fichero para poder utilizarlo en toda la aplicación, pero cuando llego hasta cierto punto estas dejan como de existir por así decirlo, me explico:

Voy del index.php que contiene codigo para verificar si hay o no una sesión:

```
<?php 
require("core.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || !isset($_SESSION['tempsess'])) {
    include(CONTROL_DIR . 'CTRindex.php');
}else{
    session_start();
    $newsess = session_id();
    $_SESSION['tempsess'] = $newsess;
    include(CONTROL_DIR . 'CTRindex.php');
}

?>
```

y de allí pues redirecciono dependiendo de si hay una o no a un controlador llamado CTRindex.php:

```
<?php 

include(VIEWS_DIR . "html/index.php");

?>
```

que lo que hace es llamar a la vista ya del index.php con un include para que se muestre dependiendo de si hay o no sesión(por el problema aún no codifico eso), bien todo funciona perfecto, en una etiqueta a en su atributo href utilizo una de estas constantes:

```
<nav>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo HTML_DIR . 'Contact.php' ?>">Contact</a></li>
</nav>
```

para llamar a un controlador, este tiene 2 includes usando las constantes que llaman a un header.php y un footer.php que son generales a todas las vistas que tengo:

```
<?php  

include(LAYOUT_DIR . "header.php");
//aquí iría contenido
include(LAYOUT_DIR . "footer.php");

?>
```

pero aquí dejan de estar definidas o eso me dice el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se vería la jerarquía de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: contacto.php tiene los require del core?

Comment: No, desde ese punto hacer un require del core.php no me deja, me explico, para poder ir desde index.php dentro de html que a su vez esta en views tendría que hacer algo como esto: require('../../core.php'); y no me deja hacer eso, me da otro error, el cual es que no encuentra dicho fichero.

Comment: pero core no esta un solo nivel arriba? un `require_once(__DIR__ . "/../core.php"); ` deberia tomarlo

Comment: Si, aún con un require_once consigue el fichero core.php pero cuando lo encuentra no se desde donde esta tratando de llamar a los fecheros del include donde estan el header.php y footer.php que con las definiciones LAYOUT_DIR que tienen la ruta dice que no encuentra los ficheros.

Comment: en los define poneles una ruta mas completa sino van a ser relativas al fichero que los use ej `define( "APP_DIR", __DIR__ . "/../app/");`

Comment: Se echa de menos una constante `ROOT` o `HOME` que apunte al directorio raíz. Yo tengo algo parecido, y he definido una constante para el root y una constante para cada carpeta. Así quedo libre de modificar los nombres de carpetas (si fuera necesario) cambiando luego el valor en la constante y nada más. Para apuntar a un archivo combino: `CARPETA+archivo` y en la definición de `CARPETA` uso `ROOT+nombrecarpeta`